# import data from select to input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just wanted to know if there is a way to import data from select tag to input tag. From a select list `<select>`, choose an option and the option value is entered automatically on input field. eg- if you select ABC from a select list, the adjacent input field will automatically have the value ABC in it.

Comment: Do you want to use external plug-ins or plain JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select_id'),
    input = document.getElementById('input_id');

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    input.value = select.value;
});
```

In jQuery:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){ 
    $('input').val($(this).val()) 
});
```

Comment: Advice : Don't answer such questions on stackoverflow. This community is for helping programmers, not the 'solve my problem' kind of people who don't show any effort.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I'm kind of against this mentality because when I began visiting this site I was the same as OP. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: Don't give people answers... If the question does not show any effort. Do you have that much free time ? If someone wants to learn, I will put as much time as they want, but if they just want a solution without any effort, they should go somewhere other than StackOverFlow.

Comment: i am actually new to java, but i tried many times to get a solution. when i couldn't, i asked it here. i am sorry if i wasted your time, and thanks to Jordan for helping me out.